# AngularJS - ng-grid pagination functionality

Tags: ng-grid

Trying to implement pagination in angularjs ng grid

```
Reference: http://plnkr.co/edit/TGIpIY?p=preview
```

Getting the grid values and values are displayed properly in the ng-grid in the result.html

controller.js

```
$scope.result = Search.getResult();
```

The search function returns 2 lists - list1 and list2

created grid as below

```
$scope.mygrid = 
{

     data : "result.list2",

     enablePaging : true,

      pagingOptions : $scope.pagingOptions,

      showFooter : true,

      .....

};
```

Now need to implement pagination for this grid.

As per the refernce site,in the function " $scope.setPagingData(data,page,pageSize);",
how to set the value for "data" ?

tried giving the value for data as "$scope.result.list2", but it throws error.

Can someone help me?

Comment: any suggestion please, i am still stuck with this issue.

Comment: make sure you have declared the $scope.pagingOptions can you specify what error you are getting or make a fiddle just to be clear what error you are getting about